# set timestamp logger in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

I put a logger in gdb script with:

```
set logging file logger.log
set logging on
```

How can I put the logger to be timestamp
like `logger_YYMMDD_HHMMSS.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python import datetime
python logfile = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('logger_%y%m%d_%H%M%S.log')
python gdb.execute('set logging file ' + logfile)
set logging on
```